# Powers of the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

> My task is to prove that for a connected bipartite graph, each of its adjacency matrix powers $A,A^2,A^3,\dots$ contains some zeros.

I started by doing the following:

The adjacency matrix has the form $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B \\ B^T & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$ where $B$ contains ones and zeros, and only contains ones for $K_{m,n}$, a complete bipartite graph. Clearly $A$ contains zeros. Now,

$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B \\ B^T & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B \\ B^T & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
BB^T & 0 \\ 0 & B^TB
\end{pmatrix}$$ and

$$A^3=\begin{pmatrix}
BB^T & 0 \\ 0 & B^TB
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B \\ B^T & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & BB^TB \\ B^TB & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ It seems like this patterns continues, with the zeros swapping between the diagonal and off-diagonal. So for $k$ even, the zeros are on the off-diagonal of $A^k$ and for $k$ odd, the zeros are on the diagonal. I'm not really sure this is enough to justify a concrete proof, so some guidance would be helpful!

Comment: That's absolutely fine. You could phrase it as a proof by induction.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I did initially attempt to prove by induction and assumed that $A^k$ contains some zeros for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, but couldn't decide what form $A^k$ would take without going by the 'it seems to follow this rule' method I went by above.